# div elements do not appear on live server in vscode

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, liveserver

I wanted to practice some CSS, so I created some divs in vscode to start playing around but when I go on live server, nothing appears.

Here is my code:*

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="" width="", initial-scale="1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .container{
            background: #81072b;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .child{
            background: #05A82C;
            width: 50%;
            height: 50%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When using width/height in percentage `%` then you need to add content inside div then it will display your css. You code is fine. Check the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/r7dju31w/)